# Fallo al conectar db en docker-compose (odoo + postgres + pgadmin)

Tags: postgresql, docker, odoo, docker-compose, pgadmin

Quiero iniciar un contenedor en docker-compose con los servicio de odoo, postgres y pgadmin.
Al ejecutar el comando "docker-compose up" inicializa los servicios pero cuando llega a odoo me sale el siguiente error: "Database connection failure: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution"

Mi archivo docker-compose.yml es el siguiente:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  odoo:
    image: odoo
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@admin.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=5050
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"

    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esta configuración que es la más cercana a la documentación de odoo:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  web:
    image: odoo
    depends_on:
      - mydb
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    volumes:
      - odoo-web:/var/lib/odoo
      //- ./config:/etc/odoo
      //- ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons
      //- ./code-configs:/home
    environment:
      - HOST=mydb
      - USER=odoo
      - PASSWORD=myodoo
    command: odoo  

  mydb:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=myodoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    volumes:
      - odoo-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata

volumes:
  odoo-web:
  odoo-db:
```